# I am trying to convert this multiIndex dataframe into a single index dataframe to divide two single index dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

[First Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EOPC.png) This is the first data frame that I am trying to use to divide.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Sensor':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 1 :[100, 103.078, 103.078, 79.0569, 55.9017, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 106.066, 125, 125], 3 :[25, 50, 50, 90.1388, 106.066, 125, 125, 100, 103.078, 103.078, 55.9017, 25, 25]}
dfDistance = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfDistance
```

And I have a second multi-index data frame that has data in it that is the same size. But since one is multi-index and the other is just a single index it is causing issues when dividing them. Is there a way I can divide the two or do I need to rip the data from the multi-index and build a single index out of it? Sorry if this post is poorly formatted this is my first time using stack overflow.
[Here is my multi-index dataframe it is generated from a .csv with lots of tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7NuS.png)

My expected output should be something like this without all the NaNs and row 13 should be .032 and .356 [Output data that is messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCwRz.png)

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your other dataframe, and also a sample of your expected output? Thank you :)

Comment: @richardec I updated the post, I assume those were what you were looking for. Thanks